# Magento: changed layout to the default one and admin crashed absolutely

Tags: templates, magento, fatal-error

Went to Configuration - Design and changed everything at template section to Default.
After that I het this at each admin page.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /home/white/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 96
```

No I can't even turn it back! How to fix it? How to turn it back at least... Maybe directly through MySQL
Also, Magento was updated from 1.5 to 1.6 not so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the table `core_config_data`

I do not recall the exact configuration paths, so you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like "%theme%"
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like "%skin%"
```

This will show you the currente theme and skin configuration settings. Then you can use an

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "workingskin" WHERE path = "configuration/path/goes/here"
```

to change the skin and theme. (the path must be replaced by what you just found out using the above `SELECT`.

Comment: @Dmitry what do u mean with: this works?! Which steps have you followed?

Comment: @Mikunos I just edited my answer so it might be more useful for others.